# What is the Origin of the Word "Sendtember" in Rock Climbing?

Tags: rock-climbing, climbing, terminology

Does anyone know the origin of the word "Sendtember"? I'm trying to figure out what it means and Google isn't being helpful. I think it has something to do with temperatures in the month of September to be more favorable for rock climbing. Any ideas?

Comment: Where did you come across that term? Can you post a reference? Maybe it's just a marketing gag by someone?

Comment: I'm not sure this is a common term.

Answer (score 7):

It's a combination of Send and September.

> Sendtember – according to climbing folklore – is blessed with perfect cool, dry, stable spring conditions in which climbers can harvest the gains made in a long winter of hard training. **September, they say, is the most sendingest month of the year.**

[Source](http://www.verticallifemag.com.au/2015/10/youve-been-wrong-about-sendtember/)

According to this article though, the number of sends actually peaks in October,

> Whilst there is an upswing in tickage in September the phenomenon **peaks in October, making it the most sendingest month.**

[Source](http://www.verticallifemag.com.au/2015/10/youve-been-wrong-about-sendtember/)

The word "send" in this context is climbing language for successfully climbing a route. A route is considered climbed successfully, when it was red-pointed, which means climbed in lead from the ground up without ever weighting the security chain (rope and quickdraws).

Comment: Sendtember just got renamed to Sileptember by Adam Ondra, strengthening its status. However one can argue that Norwegian September is more like December in most places.

Comment: Having never heard the word before, I am even more confused by what your answer means. What is "sendingest"?

Comment: @RoryAlsop the most completed projects/routes. Obviously it isn't proper English but sending a route is completing it, and "est" as a suffix means "the most." Sort of like when kids say "you're the bestest" when they mean "the best of the best."

Comment: Also since I had to look it up I think @imsodin is talking about Adam Ondra's [recent completion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adam_Ondra#Redpoint) of what may be the hardest route in the world *Silence*. In September of course..... :)

Comment: @RoryAlsop It means that it's the bestest time of the year to do the mostest sends

Comment: It's likely worth explaining what a "send" is in the answer. It's not 100% obvious if your not into the lingo, comprende?!

Comment: Another reason, not stated for September being good for climbing is the temperature. Rubber (like on climbing shoes) grips rock better when the rock is cold. As stated sept is cool and resonably dry, compared to the winter (this is already stated but just to complete the reasoning in this comment).

Comment: You've omitted to mention that the article is specifically about climbing in **Australia**. For obvious reasons, September does not and cannot provide ‘stable spring conditions’ anywhere in the Northern Hemisphere. (And even for much of the Southern Hemisphere, it’s rather questionable.)

Comment: @Pont If you look at the comments, you will see the Sendtember isn't limited to the Southern hemisphere

Comment: @CharlieBrumbaugh That’s precisely my point: since the term isn’t limited to the SH, an explanation based only on ‘spring conditions’ after a ‘winter of hard training’ doesn’t make much sense.

Comment: "the phenomenon peaks in October"  I think you mean "Rocktober".